# Join on Multiple Kafka Topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

We have a Flink application that performs window-based joins on 2 Kafka topics by key. The join configurations are as follows:

```
window-type: TumblingWindow
window-duration: 10s
allowed-lateness: 10s
```

So, the problem happens when we set the streams to start from `earliest` offset. It seems as if then the window boundaries are still set based on system-clock and thereby reject the earliest events as they depending on Kafka `retention-period` could be as old as `14 days`.

Is there a suggested way to deal with this or is there a gap in my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've configured your environment to use `EventTime`, and that you are assigning watermarks and timestamps using data contained inside the records you are reading from Kafka. If so, then it should run properly.

Note that if one of the topics has events that are much older than the other, you will get rejected (old) events. If you don't care about adding latency, you can use a `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor` to set the timestamps and watermarks, and set the max out of orderness to the maximum time skew between the two topics. If you do that, then I think you'd want to use 0 for allowed lateness.